# Unlocking a screen stalls my max priority thread running inside a service (since Lollipop)

Tags: java, android, multithreading, bluetooth, android-service

I have a max priority thread running inside a service which constantly reads data from a BluetoothSocket InputStream. The thread also normally works and should work while the screen is locked.

But, since Lollipop, I started experiencing "stalls" and "slow-downs" in the thread at the moment the screen gets unlocked (wake up), which causes me to lose data from the Bluetooth device I communicate with. Even running service as a foreground service doesn't help. Is there any solution for this, or maybe even somebody from Google I could talk to about the changes introduced in Lollipop.

Also to note, since my app is used in experimental conditions by very small amount of people (it's not even on PlayStore), a partial solution for my problem would be completely preventing the phone to be locked by the power button, if possible. Thanks.

Comment: Considering that Android is doing A LOT of optimisations on latest version regarding battery efficiency and background services and that you're running in a controlled environment. I guess your best bet is to simply preventing the phone from sleeping by enabling dev options, and set to not go to sleep while charging. Keeping the charger plugged will also prevent Doze mode and other stuff like that.

Comment: Something you could look into is the new Drawing thread that was introduced in Lollipop, which did not exist in KitKat. Basically all UI drawing and animations are on a different thread now (before that everything was on the Main Thread).

Comment: If you can produce a minimal test case (and it sounds like you probably can), you could also open an issue at http://b.android.com.